# Display multiple plotly figures in else statement

Tags: r, plotly

I want multiple [plotly](/questions/tagged/plotly) figures to be displayed from an `if` `else` statement.

```
if(iris$Sepal.Length < 0){print("Iris is NA.")
} else{
  plot_ly(x = iris$Species, y = iris$Sepal.Length, type = "bar")
  plot_ly(x = iris$Species, y = iris$Petal.Length, type = "bar")
}
```

Only the second figure appears.

If you do this with non-plotly figures, both are shown.

```
if(iris$Sepal.Length < 0){print("Iris is NA.")
} else{
  plot(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Species )
  plot(iris$Petal.Length ~ iris$Species)
}
```

Is there any way to make both appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `ncol` argument in `combineWidgets`

```
library(plotly)
if(any(iris$Sepal.Length < 0)){
  print("Iris is NA.")
 } else{ 
   p1 <- plot_ly(x = iris$Species, y = iris$Sepal.Length, type = "bar") 
   p2 <- plot_ly(x = iris$Species, y = iris$Petal.Length, type = "bar")  
   p3 <- plot_ly(x = iris$Species, y = iris$Petal.Weight, type = "bar")  
   manipulateWidget::combineWidgets(p1, p2, p3, ncol = 1)  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to display the plots outside of the else statement.

```
p1 <- NULL
p2 <- NULL

if(iris$Sepal.Length < 0){print("Iris is NA.")
} else{
  p1 <- plot_ly(x = iris$Species, y = iris$Sepal.Length, type = "bar")
  p2 <- plot_ly(x = iris$Species, y = iris$Petal.Length, type = "bar")
}

p1
p2
```

I would prefer a cleaner solution, if possible.

Comment: This is going into a markdown report and I would prefer that NULL not be reported in the case of the if statement being true.

Comment: Isn't this similar to your earlier question?  i.e. I think the only change required is with `if` condition i.e. if expects a single TRUE/FALSE input so, `if(any(iris$Sepal.Length < 0)){print("Iris is NA.")
} else{
  p1 <- plot_ly(x = iris$Species, y = iris$Sepal.Length, type = "bar")
  p2 <- plot_ly(x = iris$Species, y = iris$Petal.Length, type = "bar")
  manipulateWidget::combineWidgets(p1, p2, nrow = 1)
  
}`

Comment: I was just trying to get both plots to be displayed, not side-by-side. This solution does work for displaying both figures as side-by-side plots.

Comment: What if I want 3 plots to be displayed and I do not want them side-by-side?

Comment: You could specify the `ncol` instead of `nrow` if you want it on top